# Insert an element to std::set using constructor

Tags: c++, stl

is it possible to insert a new element to std::set like in case of std::list for example:

//insert one element named "string" to sublist of mylist

```
std::list< std::list<string> > mylist;
mylist.push_back(std::list<string>(1, "string"));
```

Now, mylist has one element of type std::string in its sub-list of type std::list.

How can you do the same in if std::set is the sub-set of std::list my list i.e

```
std::list<std::set <string>> mylist;
```

if you can't then why not?

Comment: One likely answer i'm thinking would be because a std::set doesn't accept duplicate elements, so i think you can't insert say 4 elements e.g std::set<set> (4, "string"). but there must be a way to insert at least one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "test";
    set<string> mySet(&s, &s+1);

    cout << mySet.size() << " " << *mySet.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

For clarification on the legality and validity of treating `&s` as an array, see this discussion: [string s; &s+1; Legal? UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405555/string-s-s1-legal-ub)

Comment: @Dave17: It works on the same principle as Kristo's post.  std::set has a ctor which accepts begin- and end-iterators used to initialize the contents of the new set.  I am just telling the compiler to pretend that &s+1 points to the second element in an array.  A bit of a trick, but it works for the same reason Kristo's code works -- the pointer to the last element will never be dereferenced.  Does that make sense?

Comment: `&s+1` yields the next address after `s`.  That would be legal if `s` were an array, but in this case I think it's undefined behavior.  So it only *appears* to work correctly.

Comment: @Kristo:  Yes, I was wondering about that myself.  And I was prepared to accept downvotes on this if that were the case, but I'm still not sure.  After all, you are doing the same thing:  `std::set<int> foo(&a[0], &a[5]); `  &a[5] doesn't exist.  This usage is common throughout the STL.  It is not undefined behavior because the address `&a[5]` is evaluated (possible because the size of each element is known at compile time), but not dereferenced.  I don't see how `&a[5]` can be legal while at the same time `&s+1` is not?

Comment: @Kristo:  Put another way, `&s` is akin to a pointer to an array -- an array with 1 element.

Comment: I'm going to accept it as a answer, If I get any errors on testing, I'll post an update.

Comment: @Kristo: John Dibling posted a question to get clarification on whether it's undefined behavior or not.  Bottom line - a single object can be treated as an array of one element for the purposes of pointer arithmetic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405555/string-s-s1-legal-ub

Comment: @Michael - thanks, I learned something new today.  And the Josuttis book, p. 218-219 confirms it.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` doesn't have a constructor that takes an element to be inserted.  The best you can do is use the range constructor:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::set<int> foo(a, a+5);  // insert the values 1 through 5 into foo
```

This version takes a `begin` and `end` iterator describing the range to be inserted into the set.  You can optionally supply a sorting criterion as well.  It's not quite what you wanted, but it's close.  So if you had your elements stored in a container `v`, you can insert a new set to your list like this:

```
list<set<string> > myList;
myList.push_back(set<string>(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, in C++0x:

```
    std::list<std::set<int>> foo;
    foo.push_back({1,2,3});
```

Comment: This also worked

   foo.push_back(set<string>({"foo","bar","quzz"}));